# Dynamic Component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to implement the tab view component of Prime NG. but my tabs are dynamic in nature ie. 
So when the container is loaded it sends multiple AJAX requests for data inside the component.(Maybe the component is initialized multiple times?)
Another thing, in one of the components, moving mouse gives Thousands of errors on the console.

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
```

Not sure why. Used the same component in another place and there was no issue.

Even if I remove the dynamic nature of the components and just place 4 static tabs, everything works perfectly.(Right now the same 4 components are coming from server).

Html Template:

```
<div class="col-md-12 padding0">
  <div class="tabViewWrapper">
    <p-tabView (onChange)="handleChange($event)">
      <p-tabPanel header="{{tab.tabName}}" *ngFor="let tab of tabs" >
        <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
      </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
  <div>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-view',
  templateUrl: './tab-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab-view.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  entryComponents: [GenericDataTableComponent, SingleEditCategoryExplorerComponent, AssetsDataTableComponent]
})
export class TabViewComponent implements OnInit {
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  private componentData = null;
  private tabs: Array<any>;
  private index:number;
  private disabledTabs:Array<any>;
  private disabledTabsWhenMetaDataClicked:Array<any>;

  versionConfig = {
    url: AppSettingProperties.DATA_TABLE_VALUES.VERSIONS_URL,
    dateLocale: AppSettingProperties.DATA_TABLE_VALUES.LOCALE,
    header: AppSettingProperties.DATA_TABLE_VALUES.VERSIONS_HEADER
  };

  relatedConfig = {
    url: AppSettingProperties.BASEURL + AppSettingProperties.DATA_TABLE_VALUES.RELATED_ENDPOINT,
    header: AppSettingProperties.DATA_TABLE_VALUES.RELATED_HEADER
  };

  constructor(private assetDataLoadedService: AssetDataLoadedService, private assetDetailsService: AssetDetailsService, private assetDetailDataModel:AssetDetailDataModel) { }

  @ViewChildren(DynamicContainerComponent) dynamicContainers: QueryList<DynamicContainerComponent>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.disabledTabs = [];

    //Set items to be disabled when Metadata button is clicked
    this.disabledTabsWhenMetaDataClicked = [AppSettingProperties.TAB_RELATEDITEMS, AppSettingProperties.TAB_VERSIONS];

    //Disable the tabs as per the condistions
    this.disableTabsAsPerRequirement();

    //Assigning tabs
    this.tabs = this.assetDetailsService.systemTabs;

  }
  getInitialSelected(tab){
    return this.selectedTab == this.tabs.indexOf(tab);
  }

  get selectedTab():number{
    return this.index;
  }

  set selectedTab(val:number){
    this.index = val;
    var defaultTab = this.tabs[this.index]['tabName'];

    if(!this.assetDetailDataModel.catalogId){
      this.assetDataLoadedService.assetDetailPublisher.subscribe(data=>{
        this.loadComponentByTab(defaultTab);
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
      });
    }
    else{
      this.loadComponentByTab(defaultTab);
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let tabName: string = e.originalEvent.currentTarget.innerText;
    this.selectedTab = e.index;
    //this.loadComponentByTab(tabName);    
  }

  loadComponentByTab(tabName:string){
    switch (tabName) {
      case AppSettingProperties.TAB_METADATA:
        this.componentData = { component: AssetsDataTableComponent, inputs: {} }
        break;
      case AppSettingProperties.TAB_CATEGORY:
        let categoryConfig: object = {"catalog_id":this.assetDetailDataModel.catalogId,"item_id":this.assetDetailDataModel.assetId};
        console.log(categoryConfig);
        this.componentData = { component: SingleEditCategoryExplorerComponent, inputs: { tabConfig: categoryConfig } }
        break;
      case AppSettingProperties.TAB_RELATEDITEMS:
        this.componentData = { component: GenericDataTableComponent, inputs: { tabConfig: this.relatedConfig } }
        break;
      case AppSettingProperties.TAB_VERSIONS:
        this.componentData = { component: GenericDataTableComponent, inputs: { tabConfig: this.versionConfig } }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Dynamic Component:**

```
import { Component, Input, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ReflectiveInjector, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',

  template: `<div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>`,
})
export class DynamicComponent {
  private currentComponent = null;

  @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  // component: Class for the component you want to create
  // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
  @Input() set componentData(data: { component: any, inputs: any }) {
    console.log("Building Component Start");
    if (!data) {
      return;
    }

    // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
    let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => { return { provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] }; });
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);

    // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

    // We create the component using the factory and the injector
    let component = factory.create(injector);

    // We insert the component into the dom container
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);

    // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
    if (this.currentComponent) {
      this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
    console.log("Building Component Finish");
  }  
}
```

Another thing is that the console start in dynamic component is shown 8 times.
While console finish is shown 4-5 times.

Seems really weird behavior.

Comment: Probably `this.assetDetailsService.systemTabs` is not returning an array.

Comment: Have you tried to create a Tab object which has a property tabName? And then you'll have `private tabs: Array<Tab>;`

Answer (score 0):

As @echonax wrote in comment.

This is because you are trying to iterate something that is not an array.
Most probably `this.tabs`.

You can try and write out `{{tabs|json}}` in a div instead of the `*ngFor`

Comment: Its an Array.
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
   [
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Id: 0,
         tabName: "Metadata"
      },
      1: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Id: 1,
         tabName: "Category"
      },
      2: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Id: 2,
         tabName: "Related Items"
      },
      3: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Id: 3,
         tabName: "Versions"
      },
      length: 4
   ]

Comment: Please update your question with new info (the data, and format it correctly). Because what you pasted there makes almost no sense

Answer (score 0):

Since your response takes sometime to load your DOM will have `tabs` variable as undefined array.

To solve this initialize the variable to an empty array as  below

```
tabs:Array<any> = []
```

or inside the constructor as

```
constructor(){
   this.tabs = [];
}
```